# Reuse of a path in to a function - escaping chars

Tags: python, python-2.7, string-formatting

I am trying to figure out how to reuse a path from `os.getcwd()` into a `dict.pop() call`, using the path in the same format a `print` statement will produce (Python 2.7):

```
import os
import pysvn
import sys

def svnGetExternals():
    directory = os.getcwd()              # (C:\Development\test\)
    print directory                      # prints "C:\Development\test\"
    client = pysvn.Client()
    svnExternals = client.propget('svn:externals', directory)  # returns a dictionary 
    svnExternalList = svnExternals.pop(directory).split('\n')  # returns: KeyError: 'C:\\Development\\test'
```

So, I just want to use `'C:\Development\test'` in the `pop` call.

Comment: Well what *are* the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: Actually, in the dictionary returned by pysvn, the path I am trying to pass to the command  is the key itself.

Comment: Well evidently it isn't, which is why: 1. you get a `KeyError`; and 2. I ask.

Comment: When I see the content of snvExternals I get (using eclipse with pysvn, in the watch window):       
dict:{'C:\Development\test' : 'value of the svn:external property'} 

If I put svnExternalList = svnExternals.pop('C:\Development\test').split('\n'), all is good.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to demonstrate what you have. Where did `dict:` come from? Are you using `repr`?

Comment: You are getting confused by the difference between the printable version of a string (`C:\Development\test`) and it's inner representation (`"C:\\Development\\test") - which is what you'd get using `print repr(directory)` instead of `print directory`.

Please update your code to 1. print the inner representation of the path instead of it's printable version and 2. print the exact `dict` you get from the call to `client.propget`.

Comment: Actually, even though the dictionary keys and the path are linked (the key is the svn path).   I changed my approach to use the key methods instead.  Thanks for your help guys.